# Using Host header url in Sharepoint 2013: DNS Configuration

Tags: migration, configuration, dns, host-header

I have an issue, I am trying to migrate a sharepoint 2010 to 2013. From the Microsoft documentation I understand I am to replicate all the 2010 settings including url and port number. My 2013 sharepoint farm is installed on a virtual server(Has the company's internet site runnig on it). I will like to know the following

1. Do I need to configure a dns server to use host headers(in order to replicate the 2010 url).
2. How can I setup dns server without affecting my already created web application on the 2013 farm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new DNS server, rather you need to update the DNS record.

Right now your URL /DNS pointing to the sharepoint 2010 wfe. After migrating you have to point those DNS to sp2013 wfe.

Comment: but host headers is not working on my server, it always throws 404 after creating a web application